# Jumping out of string keyboard shortcut for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, editor

While we are typing a string is there any way, except pressing right arrow button, to go out of double quotation in `Android studio` or `intellij-idea`(for example a kind of shortcut or something)

If it inserts a comma and goes to next empty field it would be better also.

for example:

```
Log.i("stingLogName|") ==> Log.i("stingLogName", |)
```

(i've shown blinking cursor with |)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in Android Studio (and of course in intelij) with `Live Templates`.

But you can move from field to field with <kbd>Tab</kbd> button (default) or if you want <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> by selecting it in the Live Templates settings.

Usage:

- Open Android Studio and place the cursor inside a statment (the `OnCreate` method for example)
- Type `logi` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> ( or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and select an element from the list)

You can find more information here [IntelliJ Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html)

Hope it helps